# Why am I getting this SQLServerException: "The result set has no current row"

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I am trying to access a database using the following code:

```java
try {   
        //Create Data Source and set properties
        SQLServerDataSource ds = new SQLServerDataSource();
        ds.setServerName(MY_SERVER);
        ds.setDatabaseName(MY_DATABASE);
        ds.setIntegratedSecurity(true);

        //Establish connection
        Connection conn = ds.getConnection();

        //Define query
        String query = "SELECT * from dbo.InvPrice;";

        //Create Statement and execute query
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

        //Print off table column names to make sure 
        //that we have actually connected to table
        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
        int numberOfColumns = rsmd.getColumnCount();
        for(int i=1; i<=numberOfColumns; i++)
            System.out.print(rsmd.getColumnName(i)+" ");

        System.out.println();

        //Check to make sure ResultSet isn't empty
        if(!rs.isBeforeFirst())
            System.out.println("NO DATA");

        //loop through ResultSet, printing off first column
        while(rs.next()); {
            System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
        } 
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        try { if (rs != null) rs.close(); } catch (Exception e) {};
        try { if (stmt != null) stmt.close(); } catch (Exception e) {};
        try { if (conn != null) conn.close(); } catch (Exception e) {};
    }

}
```

When I run the code, the correct column names are printed off, but then when I try to access the data in the ResultSet with `rs.getString(1)` a `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException` is thrown. It specifies that the "The result set has no current row", but I don't see how that is possible, since the while loop should prevent the program from trying to access data if the cursor is past the end of the data.

Answer (score 3):

There is a semi-colon after the `if` statement acting as an empty statement:

```
while(rs.next()); {  // remove the semi-colon
```

This causes the cursor of the `ResultSet` to traverse all the rows until there is no one it's pointing, thereby causing the exception.

Comment: And that kids, is how a semicolon stole an entire day from me.